# Proving this is the unique solution to this simple system of diff equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So the set of equations are these

$\frac{d \omega_x}{dt}+\Omega \omega_y =0$

$\frac{d \omega_y}{dt} - \Omega \omega_x =0$

You can easily differentiate again, get two second order linear diff equations and solve them to get that the solution is

$\omega_{x,y} = A cos(\Omega t) + B sin(\Omega t)$

Where A,B are to arbitrary constants.

Now my source (a physics book) is telling me that the solution to this system is

$\omega_x  = \omega_o cos(\Omega t)$

$\omega_y = \omega_o sin(\Omega t)$

For some reason though, I cant prove that this is the unique solution to that system. Can anyone tell me how to find this out?

Thanks.

Comment: Initial conditions (that you would have forgotten to include in your post)?

Comment: Nope. I'll post the source in case anyone wants to check it out. http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newton/node68.html

Comment: "Clearly", as they say in the source, these are not the only solutions.

Comment: But how do you know this? They only say "the solution to the above equations is:" and not "a solution to the above equations". What initial conditions have they assumed to generate such a solution?

Comment: Because every $\omega_x(t)=\omega_0\cos(\Omega t+K)$, $\omega_y(t)=\omega_0\sin(\Omega t+K)$, is also solution. The solution in the source corresponds to the initial condition $\omega_x(0)=\omega_0$, $\omega_y(0)=0$.

Comment: Hmm. You're right. I guess the real crux of my confusion is how you know your solution is of the form $\omega_x=\omega_o \cos(\Omega t+K) $, $\omega_y=\omega_o \sin(\Omega t + K')$ . I would only know how to obtain a solution to the second order diff equation I mentioned in my original question.

Comment: The method to solve this passing by the second order differential equation is quite sound provided one takes care to adjust $A$ and $B$ for $\omega_x$ with $A$ and $B$ for $\omega_y$... and then one recovers the solutions in my comment.

Comment: I tried this and it turned out to be really tedious (many unknowns). Any other methods to solve this kind of stuff I should check? Thanks btw.

Comment: Where is the tediousness? Solve $\omega_x''=-\Omega^2\omega_x$, hence $\omega_x=A\cos+B\sin$ for some "free" constants $(A,B)$, then use $\omega_y=-\Omega^{-1}\omega_x'$ to deduce that $\omega_y=-\Omega^{-1}(-A\Omega\sin+B\Omega\cos)=\ldots$